# Task Scheduler program writes to literal folder named %LOCALAPPDATA%

Tags: environment-variables, scheduled-tasks, active-directory, task-scheduler, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a .NET executable (that I created) which uses Microsoft's [Active Directory Service Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (via System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement) to do LDAP queries.  Internally to ADSI, [it downloads the Active Directory schema and stores it locally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It's supposed to store this schema in a folder at `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SchCache\`.

When I schedule this executable in **Task Scheduler** on Windows Server 2012 R2 and set it to run as "UserA" *even if that user is not logged in*, the program runs but it tries to write the above cache file into a **folder literally named `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SchCache\`** within the *start-in* folder of the scheduled task (which is intentionally set to the folder of my executable).  In other words, it's writing into something like `C:\MyApp\%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SchCache\`.  I had to give UserA explicit write permissions to this folder to allow the program to run properly.

I've watched the task's process with Process Monitor and it's immediately going to that folder.  It's not as if it first tries something in `C:\Users\` but failed.

When I log into the server as my own user and manually run the executable as UserA by using **Run as a different user**, the executable runs and successfully writes the cache file into `C:\Users\UserA\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\SchCache\`.

Why is this happening with Task Scheduler and what can I do to fix it?  I imagine it may have to do with Task Scheduler executing the program in the context of UserA but not initialaizing `%LOCALAPPDATA%` as an environment variable.  On a whim I tried setting *Run with highest privileges* on the task, but that didn't change the outcome.

Comment: Can you use [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) instead of the environment variable?

Comment: Whatever is resolving the path is within a Microsoft DLL, not my own code.

Comment: Right, but I'm suggesting to resolve the path before you pass it to the DLL.

Comment: @heavyd There is no passing of paths.  It's just a call to [`UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example.  The temporary file is all internal to the external DLL.

Comment: Is UserA a domain or local user? Has that user ever been interactively logged into the machine? Is it a standard or administrative user account? Has it been granted the [LOGON AS BATCH JOB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957131.aspx) user right?

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/540427/windows-server-2012-scheduled-tasks-run-using-default-profile-when-ran-session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Windows Server 2012 R2 and 8.1; Microsoft has documented it in [KB 2968540](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2968540).

The problem has been fixed and hotfix [KB 3133689](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3133689) is available.  This hotfix does resolve the problem.

> Scheduled tasks that are run by using UBPM don't have sufficient environment variables such as APPDATA, USERPROFILE, or TEMP when the corresponding process is started.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is a bug in Windows 7 / 2012 scheduled tasks, so that they do not see the correct environment variables for the user they are running as:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589381/

To confirm this is occurring, you could run `SET>test.txt` in a batch file in a scheduled task, in the same user context. When I try this, it does *not* show the correct, full set of environment variables for the specified user; i.e. not the same set you see if you run the same command (or batch file) when actually logged in as that user. (Even more confusingly, this depends on whether the user is currently logged in or not when the scheduled task runs; if they are logged in, then the task *does* see the correct variables.)

I think this behaviour is not documented or intended, and is a bug in the way Windows Server 2012 (maybe just R2?) scheduled tasks are handled.

**NB** This applies to the `PATH` variable too, so scheduled tasks can only see executables which are on the *default* path, or in the current directory, or with a fully specified path. Calling anything which is on the specified user's path, but not on the default path, will give a hard-to-debug (since it works in testing!) error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of the way that Windows handles user accounts. When a user account isn't logged in, their user registry hive - the key under `HKEY_USERS` that normally gets mapped as `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` - is not mounted. That hive (which is stored in a file, in each user's profile, called `NTUSER.DAT`) stores nearly all per-user data, including per-user environment variables. Windows also has system environment variables - some variables, such as PATH, are present in both locations and get merged - so those will show up even if the user's registry hive isn't mounted. None of the user-specific ones will, though.

I don't know if Task Scheduler handled this scenario differently in other Windows versions. It *could* be smart enough to mount the user's hive before running a task as that user. In Win7 / 2012R2, it apparently is not.

To fix this, you need to ensure the user's registry hive is mounted. The simplest way to do this is just to make sure the user is logged in, since a logged-in user's hive is always mounted. Lacking that, you can try mounting the hive yourself (the API is [`RegLoadKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724889(v=vs.85).aspx) but I've never tried invoking it for this).

Comment: The described scenario in this answer simply isn't possible and this answer isn't factually accurate - `%LocalAppData%` is a hard-coded system environment variable and is _not_ a user-specific variable _(it exists so a user-specific variable isn't needed, as it will always resolve to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\local` of the currently logged in user, provided they have a user profile)_. I'm unsure where the correlation with this and Registry hives is, as all that's needed is to use the full path for the non-logged in user and and not a system variable.

Comment: @JW0914 Citation? Because you 100% can relocate a user's profile directory, and with it the appdata and appdata\local directories. Furthermore at least some of the references to the [Local] AppData location are stored in the user's registry hive (e.g. HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders), although I suppose possibly not the source of %localappdata%? %USERPROFILE%, %LOCALAPPDATA%, etc. are defined in HKCU\Volatile Environment, but maybe that key only exists for the sake of caching values when logged in? But please support that claim.

Comment: So first of all, `FOLDERID_LocalAppData` **is** stored in the registry, just in HKLM (`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\` along with the other Known Folders). More to the point, though, the known folders only store _default_ locations (as your link shows); at least some Known Folders can be redirected, and at least some are per-user, and where else are you going to store a per-user redirected location than in the user registry hive?

Comment: Indeed, you can test this: redirect some useless folder (e.g. "3D Objects") to a location with a unique string, then search the registry for that string. You'll find it... in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`, a few entries up from "Local AppData". Of course, that still doesn't guarantee that the (volatile) env var comes from the "Known Folders" a.k.a. "User Shell Folders" - they could technically be distinct things that happen to point to the same location by default and changing one won't change the other - but I think the evidence is against you.

Comment: AFAIK, modifying the `%LocalAppData%` default path will result in a corrupted User Profile due to breaking hard links within it _(I may have this reversed w/ `%AppData%` and will verify in the morning - one has hard links and can't be moved)_, and once corrupted, there is no way to fix the User Profile - a new one must be created and all data copied over. User data directories within `%UserProfile%` [`3D Objects`, `Contacts`, `Documents`, etc.] are designed to be moved and will have a _Location_ tab in their folder properties for this purpose. I recommend trusting Microsoft Docs over all else.

Comment: I believe the point I'm making is being misunderstood - simply because something is in the Registry doesn't mean it's where the information is being pulled from. I linked to those Microsoft Docs articles because it shows how it's resolved in the OS' C programming, and it's not a volatile variable _(almost every application has to use the `%LocalAppData%` variable: `%LocalAppData%\Temp`)_; it's a system variable for `%UserProfile%\AppData\local`. Microsoft Docs are the Windows man pages and there is nothing I could find stating this is pulled from the Registry _(OS C programming shows this)_.

Comment: Obviously something being in the registry doesn't mean that's where it's sourced from, and the registry has Volatile keys that must come from elsewhere, but I think the thing you said about how modifying the LocalAppData default path (a registry value) produces a corrupted account is in fact extremely strong evidence that the OS is sourcing %LocalAppData% from the registry? Also, you provided a bunch of APIs but seem to assume their existence means the registry isn't the source of truth. That's weird because tons of Windows APIs are partly or entirely just indirectly accessing the registry.

Comment: Anyhow, you made an extremely strong claim "... scenario in this answer simply isn't possible and this answer isn't factually accurate" and... don't actually seem to be able to support it? You talk about "hardcoded variables" and at the same time admit that there's a location corresponding to the variable that, if you change it, produces a changed account. You talk like I'm unfamiliar with Windows OS basics (I literally worked on it). You say the docs you link "shows how it's resolved in the OS' C programming" but they don't, they just say what the API returns, and not where it comes from.

Comment: Hard links and the Registry have nothing to do with one another, please do some research on what I explained and information I have provided from Microsoft Docs, as it appears there's a fundamental misunderstanding of what's being addressed - Microsoft Docs are Windows' man pages and I will always trust them exclusively over opinions and recommend folks do the same. It appears you believe your opinion is correct - please do the due diligence required to show it is via Microsoft Docs _(as previously mentioned, I have and have been unable to find anything even hinting at what you're suggesting)_

Comment: Per [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid), it's a per user system variable to `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local`: "_`KNOWNFOLDERID` constants represent GUIDs that identify standard folders registered w/ the system as Known Folders & are installed with ≥Vista. For descriptions of these folders, see CSIDL `FOLDERID_LocalAppData`" (also [see](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsa))_. Deleting Registry keys w/ `%UserProfile%`||`%LocalAppData%` results in the variable still resolving correctly

Comment: Since "_`KNOWNFOLDERID` constants represent GUIDs_", we defer to where GUIDs are stored: "_The GUID structure stores a GUID_" via C++ programming \[[`guiddef.h`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/guiddef/ns-guiddef-guid)\]. If `%LocalAppData%`||`%UserProfile%` were dependent on the Registry for resolution, deleting `HKCU\Volatile Environment` would break them - it does not _(it's the [only place](https://imgur.com/a/DmCzXPu) in the Registry either are stored)_.